# How can I get serprog-duino to recognize a Macronix MX25L6406E chip?

Tags: bios, chromebook, eeprom

I recently manged to brick my acer C710-2384 chromebook a while ago by trying to flash the bios incorrectly. I opened it up, and looked at the motherboard, finding a Macronix MX25L6406E chip. I suspect the issue lies there.

I fortunately had an arduino handy, so I threw together a circuit which acts as a medium between flashrom(a linux command to detect, read, write to etc. flash chips) and the chip. I connected the chip to the arduino and scanned for chips, and I got a message saying that no EEPROM/flash device was found. This concerns me, because the default message from flashrom shows an "unknown SPI chip", so getting absolutely nothing makes me fear the chip is somehow broken.

Also, when I scanned for chips on a smaller nearby flash chip(I'm not messing with it because I have no idea what it is for and it's too small (256 kb) to be the BIOS, it identified that chip correctly as a W25X20 winbond chip with the correct storage size of 256 kb.

Do you know any way that I can get the macronix chip to register with my flashrom setup? I am just hoping that the chip isn't somehow broken.